# Android Soft Keyboard Obscures last elements in ScrollView

Tags: android, keyboard

I am having a form with several `EditText`s and an add `Button` at the bottom. I want to show the user add `button` when last `EditText` is in focus. I tried to scroll the layout to the bottom when last edit text is in focus by placing the below code in focus listener and in onClickListener(). User has to click twice to make the layout scroll down.

```
ScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```

also tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified|adjustResize"` in Manifest.

the xml is

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <Header/>
          <ScrollView>
              <LinearLayout>
                  <BunchOfEditText/>
                  <Button/>
              </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem in a neat way?

Comment: scrollview has only one child and you have included BunchOfEditText and Button inside it.try to take layout and include both of them inside it.by this scrollview will have layout as single child and BunchOfEditText,Button inside layout

Comment: Aah, i know i just tried to replicate the code.